# Solution for comparing adjusting scores where the teams consist of 3 vs 4 players

Tags: inequality

Searching for a method to adjustment team Golf scores when there are mixed teams 3 person & 4 person competing against each other. The game: Each team must must use x numbers of individual team scores in an 18 hole match depending on whether the team is a 3 or 4 person team:
Example: A 3 person team must use 33 scores while a 4 person team must use 44 scores, each team deciding if and what scores (if any) will be used before proceeding to the next hole. These scores can be net or gross depending on individual handicaps and must total 33/44 at the end of the round. As this is a golf game, the object is to record a team score under par, which in most cases is (72-X). The current format our group has been using is to then to divide the result by either 3 or 4.
Example Team 1 (3 person) reports a score of -14 under par. 14/3 = 4.50 
        Team 2 (4 person) reports a score of -17 under par. 17/4 = 4.25
Thus the 3 person team wins although the 4 person team has scored better. This has caused considerable discussion as what method levels the playing field. The teams are constructed using an average of the player handicaps which averaging the playing abilities of the teams. Understanding that there are many variables that conceivably influence the scores, i.e. Good play, poor play, team chemistry etc. or the luck of the draw, can you find a solution that most likely and most often will bring fairness to this format.

Answer (score 1):

It seems perfectly reasonable to me that the three-person team wins.  Presumably, the four person team recorded $17$ birdies and $227$ pars, so they achieved $4.25$ birdies per player.  Similarly, the three-person team recorded $14$ birdies and $19$ pars, so they achieved $4.67$ (not $4.50$) birdies per player.  Why shouldn't the three-person team win?

I think the way you're doing it is fine.